# Wrong calculation of values after applying the round off in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, rounding

have three values a,b,c with datatype `Decimal(15,7)`.

`a` is a summation of values `b` and `c`.

I didn't get what is wrong. What is possible way to get right result after rounding?

For example:

```
Declare @a decimal(15,7), 
        @b decimal(15,7), 
        @c decimal(15,7)

SET @a = '15212.82856500000'
SET @b = '15207.52909500000'
SET @c = '5.29947000000'
```

In above condition it returns the right result

```
select @a, @b + @c
```

But I used the round off 3 to all values it returns incorrect result.

```
select ROUND(@a, 3), ROUND(@b, 3) + ROUND(@c, 3)
```

Expected result is

```
ROUND(@a, 3) = ROUND(@b, 3) + ROUND(@c, 3)
```

Comment: Can you share your expected result and inaccurate result you are getting ?

Comment: when i directly calculate a and b+ c then its match,but i apply round off then it a and b+c not match

Comment: You have two carefully selected values. Both 15207.52909500000 and 5.29947000000 round (to three decimal places) down, but the sum of 0.00009500000 and 0.00047000000 is large enough to round up to 0.001. The unsurprising result: the sum of rounded values differs from the rounded sum of values.

Answer (score 3):

You should round the result, not each variable individually:

```
SELECT ROUND(@a + @b + @c, 3)
```

Comment: when i directly calculate a and b+ c then its match,but i apply round off then it fives wrong result

Answer (score 0):

The exact query should be

```
select ROUND(@a,3),ROUND(@b+@c,3)
```

This can gives you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you ROUND(), you deviating from the actual by a certain percentage, however tiny. Now the more you use the ROUND(), the further away you are deviating. It is always advisable to ROUND the final output.

I'm assuming the example numbers that you gave are not the actual numbers you're having issues with ?